# FFMPEG - Copy l-frame range. (-ss -to) And Re-encoding not l-frame range. And merge all?

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, video

**1-** copy between nearest -ss l-frame and -to l-frame.

**2-** Re-Encoding those not in range of l-frames

**3-** concat step 1 and 2 :)

The first seconds are wrong when cutting by copying (-c:v copy -a:v copy).
CODE:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:10:00 -to 00:40:00 -i 1.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a copy 2.mp4
```

Is it possible with ffmpeg to copy between the first and end l-frames, then Re-encoding and merge the remaining ones?

- bad video output with copy only (-c:v,a copy ) :(
- long wait with just render :(